# NicEdit new upload IE issue

Tags: javascript, editor, wysiwyg, image-uploading, nicedit

Recently NicEdit was updated to upload to imgur.com instead of imageshark.us

As you can see the "Upload Image" feature works nicely on all browsers apart from IE http://www.nicedit.com/demos.php

On IE you get the alert error "Image uploads are not supported in this browser, use Chrome, Firefox, or Safari instead."

Is there a way to make the upload work again like it use to before this update?

Look forward to your help, thank you.

Comment: You can try to implement a simple hack involving uploads and iframes to support older/non-standard browsers. NicEdit uses [FormData()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/FormData)

Answer (score 0):

IE10 will probably support html5 uploads.  Until then, encourage users to switch to a real browser :)